# Perl File::Find Windows Backslashes Directory Path

Tags: windows, perl

Is there an easy way to automatically replace the $dir backslashes with forward ones because the only way I know is manually and if the path is too long is quite annoying.
Thanks.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $dir = "E:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5";

find(\&temp, $dir);
sub temp {
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are after, but a simple regex will suffice to replace `\` with `/`:

ETA: You will have to place the paths in single quotes to preserve the backslashes, then replace them (thanks cjm for pointing that out):

```
$dir = 'E:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5';
$dir =~ s#\\#/#g;
```

Comment: I've tried that before and regex doesn't work. Usually I copy-paste the directory paths and replace the backslashes with forward ones manually and I'm looking for a way to do that automatically if possible.

Comment: Of course it works. Perhaps you did not escape the backslash? You can also use `tr#\\#/#`.

Comment: More likely, he used double quotes on the string literal (as in the code above), so the string didn't actually have any backslashes in it.  Single quotes make it easier to include literal backslashes.

Comment: The single quotes made it work. I didn't try that before. Many, many thanks.

Comment: @cjm Ah yes.. double quotes would make them `\d`, whatever that is. =P Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I misread the question so my answer doesn't make much sense (and is now deleted).

Comment: @mu I'm glad you were not offended by my blunt words. ;)

Comment: Everything is ok. No worries. Thanks again for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

What about idea of non system dependent path? There is module called [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/PathTools-3.33/lib/File/Spec.pm) in the standard perl distribution. Look at this code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec;

my $path;
$path = File::Spec->catfile("dir1","dir2","dir3","dir4","dir5");
```

Comment: On Windows, this will use backslashes, which is what the OP did not want.